# Discord.py displaying information from a dictionary using embeds

Tags: python, discord

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import bloons

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

@bot.command("info")
async def displayembed(ctx,args):

    try:
        info = bloons.data["monkeys"][args]["Description"]
        monkey_name = bloons.data["monkeys"][args]
        monkey_img = bloons.data["monkeys"][args]["Image"]
    except KeyError:
        return "You spelled the name incorrectly try again"
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=monkey_name, #using name grabbed from dictionary
            description=info, #using info grabbed from dictionary

        )
        embed.set_footer(text="This is a footer.")
        embed.set_image(url=monkey_img) #using image grabbed from dictionary
        embed.set_thumbnail(
            url="https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimg.wattpad.com%2Fcover%2F120707245-256-k661817.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wattpad.com%2F460990650-how-to-be-a-kawaii-mango-step-1&tbnid=AyEg5rQ9APuWAM&vet=10CAMQxiAoAGoXChMI8PjRsreK7gIVAAAAAB0AAAAAEAY..i&docid=VKow1SDnSKMNOM&w=256&h=400&itg=1&q=kawaii%20mango&ved=0CAMQxiAoAGoXChMI8PjRsreK7gIVAAAAAB0AAAAAEAY")
        embed.set_author(name="Author Name",
                         icon_url="https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimg.wattpad.com%2Fcover%2F120707245-256-k661817.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wattpad.com%2F460990650-how-to-be-a-kawaii-mango-step-1&tbnid=AyEg5rQ9APuWAM&vet=10CAMQxiAoAGoXChMI8PjRsreK7gIVAAAAAB0AAAAAEAY..i&docid=VKow1SDnSKMNOM&w=256&h=400&itg=1&q=kawaii%20mango&ved=0CAMQxiAoAGoXChMI8PjRsreK7gIVAAAAAB0AAAAAEAY")
        embed.add_field(name="Field Name", value="Field Value", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Field Name", value="Field Value", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Field Name", value="Field Value", inline=True)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Here's the dictionary im trying to access the information from:

```
data={
    "monkeys":{
        "Quincy":{
            "Description":"Proud, strong and intelligent, Quincy uses his bow to perform feats of amazing skill.",
            "Image":"https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/b__/images/a/a8/QuincyPortrait.png/revision/latest?cb=20190612021048&path-prefix=bloons"
        }
}
```

Error I'm receiving:

```
Ignoring exception in command info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vimalan\anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Vimalan/PycharmProjects/100CODECHALLENGE/discordbot/main.py", line 60, in displayembed
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 891, in send
    nonce=nonce, allowed_mentions=allowed_mentions)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 245, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.title: Could not interpret "{'Description': 'Proud, strong and intelligent, Quincy uses his bow to perform feats of amazing skill.', 'Image': 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/b__/images/a/a8/QuincyPortrait.png/revision/latest?cb=20190612021048&path-prefix=bloons'}" as string.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vimalan\anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.title: Could not interpret "{'Description': 'Proud, strong and intelligent, Quincy uses his bow to perform feats of amazing skill.', 'Image': 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/b__/images/a/a8/QuincyPortrait.png/revision/latest?cb=20190612021048&path-prefix=bloons'}" as string.
```

What I'm trying to attempt to do was, grab information from a dictionary I've created which listed the monkeys name, description and image, and what I'd like to do was when the user types in `$info "monkey name"` it would populate the embedded template with the given information and display it. But I've gotten quite a bit of errors trying to do that and I'm not too sure how to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

It was accessing a dictionary rather than grabbing the name of the monkey it self, which might've caused the error.
I should've just called put the arg itself as the title...